# Cannot connect SSH from remote server

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, sftp, heroku

I'm having trouble connecting sFTP vis SSH from my cloud server. I am using a proxy to connect and have allowed the IP addresses. When I connect from my local server using the same proxy, the connection is successful. This only causes issues when I try to connect from my Heroku server (Built on top of AWS). My logs server don't seem to be very useful.

Here is where the unsuccessful connection from the cloud server closes connection (Using a proxy)

```
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
debug2: monitor_read: 100 used once, disabling now
debug3: mm_inform_authserv entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 4 [preauth]
debug2: input_userauth_request: try method none [preauth]
debug3: userauth_finish: failure partial=0 next methods="publickey" [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 4
debug3: mm_answer_authserv: service=ssh-connection, style=, role=
debug2: monitor_read: 4 used once, disabling now
sshd[1496]: Connection closed by 11.111.11.108 [preauth]
debug1: do_cleanup [preauth]
debug3: PAM: sshpam_thread_cleanup entering [preauth]
debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug1: do_cleanup
debug1: PAM: cleanup
debug3: PAM: sshpam_thread_cleanup entering
debug1: Killing privsep child 1497
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 49545
```

Here is the successful connection from my local server at the same point where the unsuccessful closes connection (Using the same proxy)

```
1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
2: monitor_read: 100 used once, disabling now
3: mm_inform_authserv entering [preauth]
3: mm_request_send entering: type 4 [preauth]
2: input_userauth_request: try method none [preauth]
3: userauth_finish: failure partial=0 next methods="publickey" [preauth]
3: mm_request_receive entering
3: monitor_read: checking request 4
3: mm_answer_authserv: service=ssh-connection, style=, role=
2: monitor_read: 4 used once, disabling now
1: userauth-request for user dev service ssh-connection method publickey [preauth]
1: attempt 1 failures 0 [preauth]
2: input_userauth_request: try method publickey [preauth]
1: test whether pkalg/pkblob are acceptable [preauth]
3: mm_key_allowed entering [preauth]
3: mm_request_send entering: type 22 [preauth]
3: mm_key_allowed: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_KEYALLOWED [preauth]
3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 23 [preauth]
3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
3: mm_request_receive entering
3: monitor_read: checking request 22
3: mm_answer_keyallowed entering
```

Both of these connection attempts are identical (Same proxy, same user, same keys). I'm really at a loss here at the moment, does anyone have any idea what I can do to resolve this?

Comment: These are from the logs on the ssh server. Am I looking at the wrong thing?

Comment: OK, it makes sense now. It looks like your ssh client didn't try any keys. Are you sure it actually has a key to use?

Comment: Yeah, when I check the server for `~/.ssh/id_rsa` it is 100% there. It's in same location as my local server.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that: The IP address of the remote machine is correct. The port SSH daemon is listening to is not blocked by a firewall or forwarded incorrectly. Your username and password are correct